# Keras: regularizing loss for an output based on the other outputs

Tags: keras, deep-learning, loss-function, regularized, multipleoutputs

#### Setup

I have a model with 3 inputs and 2 outputs (figure below). I have a defined loss per each output, but then I want to add a regularization term to each loss which is a function of two outputs:

```
L_V = MSE(v,y_v) + lambda_ * f(v, q)
L_Q = MSE(q,y_q) + lambda_ * f(v, q)
```

the regularizer `f(v, q)` is like an additional restriction, e.g. let's say I want to solve a trade-off problem of fitting Q and V, but also minimizing the dot product of `v.q`.

[image: network]

#### Question

Without regularizer, I can pass my two losses in `model.compile(loss = [v_loss, q_loss])`. But how can I define the regularizer? My main challenge is how to read the value of other output in the custom `v_loss` function, to evaluate `f(v,q)` on that.

#### What I tried and failed

I concatenated V and Q in a single output, and returned a loss of `L_v + L_q + L_regu`. but the network doesn't learn anything even for the simplest linear data with enough iteration. I think the main problem is that the Q network is trained also by `L_v` and likewise, V network is trained also by `L_q`, which is wrong.

Comment: Maybe you have an error in your custom loss function. Or maybe the `L_regu` is much larger than `L_v` and `L_q`, and so you are minimizing only `L_regu` but not `L_v` and `L_q`

Comment: on the contrary, `L_regu` is smaller even in the order of magnitude. Even when I set lambda to really small value, it doesn't train. as I mentioned, I think the loss `L_v+L_q` is being applied to both `v` and `q`. I'm not sure though if this is the reason

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, because the network "knows" how your loss is calculated. Adding L_q to L_v has no effect on how the weights of V affect the loss, so it doesn't affect the gradient of the  V weights

Comment: In this case, (ignoring completely the regularizer) if I have to outputs `V` and `Q` and two separate loss of `L_v` and `L_q`, I must get the same results as if I have concatenated output `[V,Q]` and one single loss `L_v+L_q`? I did both and the network wasn't trained in latter but trained in the former. But I'll double check to make sure it isn't a silly mistake